# Integration Pyspark ans Python in the same Notebook

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks, analytics

I work in the team of Analytics in X company. We use Microsoft Azure - Data Bricks. There we have to use PysPark. Let say, after different chunks we had a final data frame. I have to make use of visualisations based on this data frame. I think the library Seaborn from Python should be more useful that any library from Pyspark for data visualization. Is there a way in which I can integrate both programming lengagues in the same Notebook?

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. Pyspark can be used as a Python library with `import pyspark`, so you can use a regular Python notebook, you just need to create a Spark session by yourself. Please clarify what the issue is.

Comment: databricks notebook had been designed such way that we can use python and pyspark code in same notebook . We can convert pyspark objects like to python variable and other way around as well in any time during program flow. https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/notebooks-use.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Databricks includes extra Python libraries natively, so the *Seaborn* you have mentioned, will work out of the box, with up-to-date runtime releases. Depending whether you use an ML Databricks runtime or just a regular one, the runtime will include a different set of extra Python lib. You can find the complete list of all of them in the documentation - I am attaching link to currently newest runtime versions (11.3 LTS)

- [Databricks Runtime 11.3 LTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/release-notes/runtime/11.3#installed-python-libraries)
- [Databricks Runtime 11.3 LTS for Machine Learning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/release-notes/runtime/11.3ml#python-libraries-on-cpu-clusters)

If you want to see an example Databricks notebook that integrates these libraries, [this one](https://www.databricks.com/notebooks/02_model.html) should give you some hint on how to start.